# Generating short, random and unique string on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, random

I want to generate string ids which have following properties:

1. short, up to 5-6 apha + numbers
2. random
3. unique, desired, but not so important as first too

Currently I am thinking about:

1. allocate unique id with https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids
2. hash it with some secret key, md5(id + secret)
3. take first 5 symbols

Is there a better way? I thought also about using datacenter_id + instance_id + request_id , but I have no idea if it will be better.

Comment: Is an UUID toooo long for you? :) [LINK](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

Comment: I currently use UUID, but want to add short URLs for guys who are using app from smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just generate a random string using random.choise?

```
for _ in xrange(5):
  yield random.choice(digits + alpha)
```

This has a space of 36^5 keys

Comment: I thought that hash of unique number will be more unique. I still think so, but I know nothing about cryptography.

Comment: You might also want to look at using Base32 for your alphabet, it works very nicely for URLs, filenames etc. A Base32 encoded integer will give you a string 1 - 7 characters long if you don't care about fixed length.